# Find the order of the poles of $\dfrac{z}{\cos z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

I know that they are simple poles, but how can you find this?
The usual equation that I have for finding the order of poles which is, 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^{n}f(z),
$$ 
and seeing at which $n$ this goes to zero doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Maybe it'll be helpful to think about the orders of zeros of $\cos(z)$.

Answer (score 5):

$g(z)=\cos z$ is an entire function which possesses zeros only at $z=k\pi+\pi/2$, and the zeros are simple. They are simple because $g'(z)=-\sin z$, does not vanish at $z=k\pi+\pi/2$.

Thus,
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{g(z)}=\frac{z}{\cos z},
$$
has singularities, all simple poles, at $z=k\pi+\pi/2$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Why are the zeros simple?

Comment: @JoeJohn: See updated version.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm afraid I still don't understand the relevance of the derivative not being equal to zero.

Comment: @JoeJohn: If $z_0$ is a multiple zero of $f$ (say of order $k$), then $$f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=\cdots=f^{(k-1)}(z_0)=0$$.

Comment: Thank you so much Yiorgos! Massive help.